# Any shortcut operator for negating a boolean var other than a=!a

Tags: java, boolean, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Just for learning's sake, I tried in java doc but I did not find it. Maybe some special trick with any operator like `!!` or `--`

I like auto-incremental like in `i++ = i=i+i`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No that's the shortest way to negate a `boolean`. It's really only one character more than `++` and not a super-widely used construct anyways (at least compared to something like `i++`).

Answer (score -2):

You can use negate function

```
negate(java.lang.Boolean bool)
```

Comment: `negate()` throws the `NumberFormatException`, if it finds the value other than `integer` or `double`.

Comment: public static java.lang.Boolean negate(java.lang.Boolean bool)from BooleanUtils class